# Aggregate document multilevel

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Now consider the case , i have one document containing below collection like structure. 
Below is the **order collection**

```
{

        "_id" : ObjectId("5788fcd1d8159c2366dd5d93"), 
        "color" : "Blue", 
        "code" : "1", 
        "category_id" : ObjectId("5693d170a2191f9020b8c815"), 
        "description" : "julia tried", 
        "name" : "Order1", 
        "brand_id" : ObjectId("5b0e52f058b8287a446f9f05")

}
```

There is also a collection for Brand and Category. This is the 
**Category collection**

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5693d170a2191f9020b8c815"), 
"name" : "Category1", 
"created_at" : ISODate("2016-01-11T20:32:17.832+0000"), 
"updated_at" : ISODate("2016-01-11T20:32:17.832+0000"), 
}
```

**Brand Collection**

```
{ 
   "_id" : ObjectId("5b0e52f058b8287a446f9f05"), 
   "name" : "brand1", 
   "description" : "brand1", 
   "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-07-05T09:18:13.951+0000"), 
   "created_at" : ISODate("2017-07-05T09:18:13.951+0000"), 
}
```

**Now after aggregation applied, it should result in below format:**

```
{
    'brands': [
             {
                _id: '*******'
                name: 'brand1',

                categories: [
                   {
                      _id: '*****',
                      name: 'category_name1',
                      orders: [
                          {
                              _id: '*****',
                              title: 'order1'
                          }

                      ]

                   }
                ]
             }
     ]
}
```

Comment: Question is not clear... Try to post your collection and explain it more

Comment: @Ashish Orders is collection which contain brand and category id. I want to group order by brand and category, need result above shown format.

Comment: Output result should in Multiple brands in outerscope, brands may contain categories and categories should contain orders

Comment: update your question instead of commenting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation:

```
db.brand.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "order",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "brand_id",
            as: "orders"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$orders"
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "category",
            localField: "orders.category_id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "categories"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$categories"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            name: { $first: "$name" },
            description: { $first: "$description" },
            updated_at: { $first: "$updated_at" },
            created_at: { $first: "$created_at" },
            categories: { $addToSet: "$categories" },
            orders: { $addToSet: "$orders" }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            categories: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$categories",
                    as: "category",
                    in: {
                        $mergeObjects: [ 
                            "$$category", { 
                                orders: [ { 
                                    $filter: { 
                                        input: "$orders", 
                                        as: "order", 
                                        cond: { $eq: [ "$$category._id", "$$order.category_id" ] } 
                                    } 
                                } ]
                         } ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            orders: 0
        }
    }
])
```

Basically you have to use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) twice to "merge" data from all these collections based on `brand_id` and `category_id` fields. Since you expect `orders` in `categories` in `brands` you can use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) for both arrays and then use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) to get following shape:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b0e52f058b8287a446f9f05"),
    "name" : "brand1",
    "description" : "brand1",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-07-05T09:18:13.951Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-07-05T09:18:13.951Z"),
    "categories" : [
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5693d170a2191f9020b8c814"),
                    "name" : "Category1",
                    "created_at" : ISODate("2016-01-11T20:32:17.832Z"),
                    "updated_at" : ISODate("2016-01-11T20:32:17.832Z")
            }
    ],
    "orders" : [
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5788fcd1d8159c2366dd5d93"),
                    "color" : "Blue",
                    "code" : "1",
                    "category_id" : ObjectId("5693d170a2191f9020b8c814"),
                    "description" : "julia tried",
                    "name" : "Order1",
                    "brand_id" : ObjectId("5b0e52f058b8287a446f9f05")
            }
    ]
}
```

Now you have `brand1` with all its subcategories and all orders that should be placed in one of those categories. The only thing is how to "nest" `orders` in `categories`. One way to do that might be [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) where you can merge each category with all orders that match that category (using [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) you don't have to specify all properties from categories object).

To match `category` with `orders` you can perform [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) on `orders` array.

Then you can drop `orders` since those are nested into categories so you don't need them anymore.

### EDIT: 3.4 version

In MongoDB 3.4 you can't use `$mergeObjects` so you should specify all properties for `categories:

```
db.brand.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "order",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "brand_id",
            as: "orders"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$orders"
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "category",
            localField: "orders.category_id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "categories"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$categories"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            name: { $first: "$name" },
            description: { $first: "$description" },
            updated_at: { $first: "$updated_at" },
            created_at: { $first: "$created_at" },
            categories: { $addToSet: "$categories" },
            orders: { $addToSet: "$orders" }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            categories: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$categories",
                    as: "category",
                    in: {
                        _id: "$$category._id",
                        name: "$$category.name",
                        created_at: "$$category.created_at",
                        updated_at: "$$category.updated_at",
                        orders: [ 
                            { 
                                $filter: { 
                                    input: "$orders", 
                                    as: "order", 
                                    cond: { $eq: [ "$$category._id", "$$order.category_id" ] } 
                                } 
                            } 
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            orders: 0
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: I am using mongodb 3.4

Comment: @Sanjiv modified my answer, I believe `$mergeObjects` is the only operator you can't use in `3.4`

Comment: Yes, $mergeObjects operator is available since mongodb 3.6

Comment: It returns zero document

Comment: @Sanjiv I had to change few ObjectIds in your sample data when I was testing this since there's no match between `_id` properties

Comment: did you chage the value of _id or add some new _id field ?

Comment: I assumed that if your sample data has "category_id" : ObjectId("5693d170a2191f9020b8c815") then _id in categories should be the same and the same applies for brands. Otherwise question makes no sense :)

Comment: Yes, somehow it was mismatching earlier, now fixed data

Comment: Somehow orders list not getting populated and same category list getting duplicated under a particular brand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172536/discussion-between-mickl-and-sanjiv).